# How to stop reference a data frame in a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to build a function in such a way that once i supplied data='name of data frame' there is no need to write variable=data$variable as just writing variable name from the supplied data frame will serve the purpose

```
myfunction<-function(variable,data)
{
result=sum(data)/sum(variable)
return(result)
}
```

for example i have a data frame df

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=2:6,z=3:7,u=4:8)
```

I want to provide following input

```
myfunction(variable=x,data=df)
```

instead of below input to serve the purpose

```
myfunction(variable=df$x,data=df)
```

Comment: I would have `variable` be character. Two flies...

Answer (score 1):

We can use non-standard evaluation:

```
myfunction <- function(variable, data) {
  var <- eval(substitute(variable), data)
  result = sum(data)/sum(var)
  return(result)
}

# Test
myfunction(variable = x, data = df)
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The `with` or `attach` functions can help you here, see the `?with` and `?attach` documentation. Alternatively, you can supply the variable name as a `character` and use this in the function body. I.e. you can do something like this:

```
myfunction2 <- function(variable, data) {
  result <- sum(data)/sum(data[[variable]])
  return(result)
}

df <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=2:6,z=3:7,u=4:8)

myfunction2("x", df)
#[1] 6
```

Yet another resort is to use non-standard evaluation. A small example of this is something like:

```
myfunction3 <- function(variable, data) {
  var.name <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  result <- sum(data)/sum(data[[var.name]])
  return(result)
}

myfunction3(variable = x, data = df)
#[1] 6
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Supplying variable names as a character is something which i think non-standard as it makes my not not reusable. Please tell me how to do this 'with' and 'attach' function